# What did Professor Bernardo de la Paz mean exactly in his quote from The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress?

Tags: quotes, the-moon-is-a-harsh-mistress

One of the many famous quotes from Professor Bernardo de la Paz in Robert Heinlein's *The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress* is the following, originating from his discussion with Wyoming on what they believe in.

> "I will accept any rules that you feel necessary to your freedom. I am free, no matter what rules surround me. If I find them tolerable, I tolerate them; if I find them too obnoxious, I break them. I am free because I know that I alone am morally responsible for everything I do."

How exactly does the Professor accept a rule and yet break them? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: It's pretty clear - *"I tolerate them; if I find them too obnoxious, I break them."* - He's just reserving the right to accept the rule but break it if it impacts him negatively.

Comment: Think about speed laws, we all break them but we accept that if we break them we accept the responsibility for the outcome.

Comment: @Paulie_D - hey, speak for yourself! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply that he isn't interested in trying to stop anyone from *making* rules that he disagrees with. If it makes people happy to make rules — good for them. If it makes people happy to be governed by those rules — good for them. He won't interfere. But to him rules enacted by democracies or committees or despots have no moral weight; he will act to do what is right and avoid what is wrong, according to his own understanding, irrespective of the law.

Comment: Spoiler alert, but he does interfere :-)

Answer (score 6):

This question may be better suited for politics or philosophy SE /s

Heinlein was a [libertarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarianism), and his works both fiction and non-fiction covered that [point of view](https://www.libertarianism.org/topics/heinlein-robert-1907-1988).  From that last link Heinlein himself is quoted as:

> I would say my position is not too far from that of Ayn Rand’s; that I
> would like to see government reduced to no more than internal police
> and courts, external armed forces—with the other matters handled
> otherwise. I’m sick of the way the government sticks its nose into
> everything, now.… It seems to me that every time we manage to
> establish one freedom, they take another away. Maybe two.

The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress has been [called](https://www.adamsmith.org/blog/the-moon-is-a-harsh-mistress)

> His libertarian masterpiece

So basically Prof de la Paz is espousing his (or Heinlein's) libertarian viewpoint that (among other things) a person is soley responsible for their own actions, and nobody has the right to control anyone else (1)

Thus a libertarian will do what they please, regardless if it aligns with any laws/rules or not.

---

(1) I am not a political scientist and I only have a basic idea of libertarian principles, so please excuse any excessive simplification.